# How to remove or hide decimals on weight values in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide decimals due to stating the weight in g and displaying decimals seems unnecessary. The function of woocommerce's wc-formatting-functions.php:

```
/**
 * Format a weight for display.
 *
 * @since  3.0.0
 * @param  float $weight Weight.
 * @return string
 */
function wc_format_weight( $weight ) {
    $weight_string = wc_format_localized_decimal( $weight );

    if ( ! empty( $weight_string ) ) {
        $weight_string .= ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' );
    } else {
        $weight_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_format_weight', $weight_string, $weight );
}
```

Any ideas of how to change the way the weight is displayed? Maybe I should do this via CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to change the formatted weight in WooCommerce removing decimals:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_weight', 'custom_format_weight', 90, 2 );
function custom_format_weight( $weight_string, $weight ){

    $weight_string  = intval( $weight );

    if ( ! empty( $weight_string ) ) {
        $weight_string .= ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' );
    } else {
        $weight_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $weight_string;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*